# Variable does not exist: Name?

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Name at line 8 column 87

Code:

```
trigger DuplicatePrevention on Account (before insert) {

        List<Account> acclist = new List<Account>();
        for(Account a:Trigger.new)
        {
                 acclist.add(a);
        }
        List<Account> olist = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN 
        :acclist.Name];


}
```

Comment: If you also created **[this account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/49792/dinesh-kumar)**, please **[contact](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact)** the community team to get them merged. It is *especially* important you do not maintain multiple accounts if one of yours got question-banned, as that is then seen as trying to circumvent the system, which is abusive behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Your `acclist` variable is a `List<Account>`, which has no `Name` property. If you want to collect the `Name` values, use a `Set<String>`:

```
Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
for (Account record : trigger.new)
{
    names.add(record.Name);
}
List<Account> duplicates = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :names];
```